# Standing in a field. What is my name?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I was standing in a field reading a map

and doing something characteristic of me

I felt the urge to take a power nap

but first I needed to go for a pee

Comment: Great riddle! Now I want to add a certain tag to the question, but obviously that would be too big a spoiler ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, of *course* ...

> It's a mathematical riddle. I should have realised sooner.

*I was standing in a field reading a map*

> A **field**, as in the [mathematical object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_theory_(mathematics)): a set with two binary operations. A **map**, as in a function acting on elements of this field.

*and doing something characteristic of me*

> The **characteristic** of a field, in the [ring-theoretic sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) - the characteristic of any field is always either zero or a positive prime number.

*I felt the urge to take a power nap*

> A **power**, as in taking powers of elements. The "power nap" here probably means a power *map*.

*but first I needed to go for a pee*

> A **pee**, meaning a prime number $p$, the characteristic of the field.

So taking all in all, you are

> a **[Frobenius endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism)**: the map sending any element of a **field** of **characteristic** $p$ to its $p$th **power**.

---

**Feedback section**

When I saw [Silenus's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51015/5373), I thought that was it and the riddle was solved. But then I noticed the bounty and realised that this wasn't done and dusted yet. The second line was what really did it for me: that unusual word "characteristic" must have been chosen for a reason, so why? Then I thought of what might be standing in a field (for a while I wondered if the solution might be "scarecrow"), and why a *field* specifically. Eventually it clicked that "field" doesn't mean what you'd first think it does, and everything else just snowballed from there. Exactly as it should with a well-constructed riddle: it seems inscrutable at first, but once you get a hold on it, the solution is self-confirming. My only criticism would be that it took a while for me to get the final solution even after I'd realised what the riddle is all about, but we can put that down to the fact that it's been a few years since I've studied any

> algebra.

Comment: @Improve and other puzzle setters - "I thought that was it and the riddle was solved. But then I noticed the bounty and realised that this wasn't done and dusted yet" - just a note that if you don't comment on a wrong answer, people may not know if you've seen it but it's wrong, or if you just haven't seen it.  A note on incorrect answers is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

You are a

> storm cloud, perhaps.

---

I was standing in a field reading a map

> A cloud might stand high above a field and look down upon the earth, which resembles a map.

and doing something characteristic of me

> This action of hovering above earth is characteristic of clouds.

I felt the urge to take a power nap

> "*Power* nap" may refer to lightning.

but first I needed to go for a pee

> The cloud needed to produce rain, since moisture is essential for thunderstorms.